# Getting wrong results with awk

Tags: csv, awk

I have a dataset from which I am trying to select rows with values in a column called `ambienf` greater than 20.

First, find the column number:

```
$ csvcut -n head.csv | grep ambienf
287: ambienf
```

Next, look at the values:

```
$ csvcut -c name,ambienf head.csv | head -n 25 | csvlook
|-----------+-------------------|
|  name     | ambienf           |
|-----------+-------------------|
|  87892625 |                   |
|  87881401 | 31.3340396881104  |
|  87881407 | 23.3398342132568  |
|  87881397 |                   |
|  87892628 |                   |
|  87892632 |                   |
|  87881394 | 28.8716373443604  |
|  87790338 |                   |
|  87797472 |                   |
|  87788161 | 32.2283515930176  |
|  87790894 | 32.7088813781738  |
|  87871678 | 25.5556793212891  |
|  87767487 | 33.3377380371094  |
|  87759792 |                   |
|  87751064 |                   |
|  87772221 |                   |
|  87751071 |                   |
|  87751061 |                   |
|  87751067 |                   |
|  87772224 |                   |
|  87756101 | 32.2252311706543  |
|  87747384 | 30.0030345916748  |
|  87767382 | 22.2242679595947  |
|  87720411 |                   |
|  87728035 |                   |
|  87711021 |                   |
|-----------+-------------------|
```

Now, I want to select name ($3) and ambienf ($287) where ambienf is > 20:

```
$ awk -F , '$287 > 20 {print $3 "," $287}' head.csv
name ambienf
```

^ that’s all I get as an output. If I do `awk -F, '{print $3 "," $287}' head.csv | head -20 | csvlook`, I get the same result as with the `csvcut -c name,ambienf` command above.

Any help with troubleshooting would be appreciated!

Comment: @alvits, that isn't true at all. `awk` has a concept of variable typing which will treat those values as numeric, as evidenced by `printf '1.2 a\n0.2 b\n' | awk '$1 > 1 {print}'` giving you `1.2 a`.

Comment: Also make sure your values are not quoted. Check the raw format  data with `head` only.

Comment: Bingo! My values are quoted. Not sure why. How do I get rid of that?

(My attempts of string conversion to numbers or vice versa didn’t work.)

Answer (score 1):

The issue was the numerical values for some reason being quoted. I found another version of the dataset with the numbers unquoted, and my commands ran on it. Thanks @karakfa!